# Error when scraping Amazon reviews with Rstudio: arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 10

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi I am a beginner in coding and only have marginal understandings with how things work.

I am currently trying to scrape Amazon reviews with rvest package in Rstudio.

My goal is to scrape 10 pages of reviews each for ~400 product id (ASIN)s.

The function I used is the following:

```
scrape_amazon <- function(url, throttle = 0){
  
  # Install / Load relevant packages
  if(!"pacman" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"]) install.packages("pacman")
  pacman::p_load(RCurl, XML, dplyr, stringr, rvest, purrr)
  
  # Set throttle between URL calls
  sec = 0
  if(throttle < 0) warning("throttle was less than 0: set to 0")
  if(throttle > 0) sec = max(0, throttle + runif(1, -1, 1))
  
  # obtain HTML of URL
  doc <- read_html(url)
  
  # Parse relevant elements from HTML
  title <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .a-color-base") %>%
    html_text()
  
  author <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .a-profile-name") %>%
    html_text()
  
  date <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .review-date") %>%
    html_text() %>% 
    gsub(".*on ", "", .)
  
  
  stars <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list  .review-rating") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract("\\d") %>%
    
    as.numeric() 
  
  comments <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .review-text") %>%
    html_text() 
  
  n_helpful <- doc %>%
    html_nodes(".a-expander-inline-container") %>%
    html_text() 
  
  
  # Combine attributes into a single data frame
  n_helpful <- data.frame(n_helpful, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  n_helpful <- n_helpful[-1,]
  df2 <- data.frame(title, author, date, stars, comments, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  dff <- cbind(n_helpful, df2)
  return(dff)
}
```

Then I scraped for a single page to make sure that it worked:

```
url <- "http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B00836Y6B2/?pageNumber=1"
reviews <- scrape_amazon(url)
```

.. and confirmed that it works.

Then I set the number of pages to be scraped to 10, read in the csv file that contains the table of ASINs, made an empty dataframe so that reviews of each ASINs will add up to the empty dataframe.

Running the following codes successfully returned all reviews for ASIN 1 to 10.

However, the following error message showed up when I was attempting 11 to 20.

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 10
```

```
# Set # of pages to scrape. Note: each page contains 8 reviews.
pages <- 10


# loop over pages
Asins <- read.csv("ASINs.csv")

reviews_total <- data.frame()

for(prod_cod in Asins[1:10,]){ 
    for(page_num in 1:pages){
    url <- paste0("http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/",prod_cod,"/?pageNumber=", page_num)
    reviews1 <- scrape_amazon(url, throttle = 4)
    reviews_total <-rbind(reviews_total, reviews1)}
  }

for(prod_cod in Asins[11:20,]){ 
  for(page_num in 1:pages){
    url <- paste0("http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/",prod_cod,"/?pageNumber=", page_num)
    reviews1 <- scrape_amazon(url, throttle = 4)
    reviews_total <-rbind(reviews_total, reviews1)}
}
```

I am very confused at this moment as the error message is inconsistent.

My code is based on the instructions in this link: https://justrthings.com/2019/03/03/web-scraping-amazon-reviews-march-2019/

but many of the lines didn't work for me so I changed a little bit.

Please let me know if you need any more information upon resolving this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but i have following code that may help you out, my goal is to review certain products that are stored in an excel file with direct connection to several databases. It's name will be **"*csv*"**

***csv***  has this overview:
| Product_name   |    ASIN   |
|---------------|------------|
|   chr        |     chr     |
| OWLURAL     |       B08F3ZN25P |
| ... with 348 more rows

This are the steps i follow:

- Create a global df with where store the information i need

```
     <- data.frame()
```

- Also create a variable that will be added 1 each loop that the script will make, this will be used to access each file of the csv where all the productnames and ASINs are stored

```
    contador <- 1
```

- We have to make a loop for all the different ASINs and make another loop to access each review page, where there will be 10 comments/page. For this, we will use the for(***x*** in ***i***){}. Where ***x*** is the value to be changed each loop and ***i*** is the value to be given to x.
- Let's get inside each ASIN and know how many reviews it has, then we will have to divide it by 10 (comments/pages) to see how many pages we have to check inside each ASIN.

```
    for(j in csv$ASIN){
      url_2<-paste0("https://www.amazon.es/Kensington-1500109ES-Teclado-USB-cable/product-reviews/***",j,"***/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews")
      pagina_reviews2<-read_html(url_2)
     val_total = pagina_reviews2 %>%
        html_nodes(".a-color-secondary") %>%
        html_text()
      val_total = str_extract(val_total[1], "[0-9]*") / 10
```

- Supossing that all the ASINS have at least 1 review...
  We create empty variables where store that information we want to get from the link

```
  review_bodies = c()
  review_titles = c()
```

- Now, changing only the number of the page at the end of any link, within the ASIN, we will be able to access every single page for each one.

```
for(i in 1:val_total){
    url<-paste0("https://www.amazon.es/NGS-FORTRESS900V2-Sistema-alimentaci%C3%B3n-ininterrumpida/product-reviews/***",j,"***/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_3?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=***",i,"***")
  
    
    # Download each page
    pagina_reviews<-read_html(url)
    print(pagina_reviews)
    
    # We get all the review information, including if the pruchase was verified, different styles, colours, etc
    review_body_page <- pagina_reviews %>%
      html_nodes(".review-data") %>%
      html_text()
    
    review_bodies = c(review_bodies, review_body_page)
    review_bodies <- gsub("\\n","",review_bodies)
    review_bodies <- review_bodies[nchar(as.vector(review_bodies)) != 0]
    
    # The filter of reviews of each group of amazon categories
    review_bodies <- review_bodies[ !grepl("^Tama", review_bodies)]
    review_bodies <- review_bodies[ !grepl("^Potencia:", review_bodies)]
    review_bodies <- review_bodies[ !grepl("^Color:", review_bodies)]
        
    
    # We need the title now of each review
    review_title_page<- pagina_reviews %>%
      html_nodes(".a-text-bold span") %>%
      html_text()
    
    review_titles = c(review_titles, review_title_page)
    review_titles = review_titles[nchar(as.vector(review_titles)) != 0]
```

Now it will depend the use you need, you can capture more variables in this loop over loop

You can now merge both ***review_titles*** with ***review_bodies*** and store them
in the df created at the beginign ***resultado_GLOBAL***